# In Freshdesk how to setup GTM tag to track Live chat?

Tags: google-tag-manager, freshdesk

I want to track live chat in Freshdesk using google tag manager. Currently I am unable to track it using google tag manager as the pop up window for chat disappears when I go to google tag manager preview mode.